# Passing result from sevlet to javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, cookies

I have got a sevlet that will return some values back to the submission page and there are some javascript function are acting base on these returning values.

I have been trying to use cookie or session as the method to pass the values, however, jquery function .cookies or .session are not able to retrieve any of those values on the page. However, they are retrievable though <% tag %>.

Rather than manually set a hidden input tag with values though <% %> and then read the tag value though the js function when the document is ready, is there any better way to handle these?

Kindly Regards

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is generate a Javascript object using your jsp, like:

```
<script text='text/javascript'>

var response = {
     answer1: '<% YOUR DATA HERE %>',
     answer2: '<% YOUR DATA HERE %>'
}

</script>
```

this way, you'll have your data available from javascript: alert(response.answer1)

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly on the jsp page, but how about though those function declare inside .js file?

Comment: The idea is to create a "virtual" js file, which really is an action  which renders a jsp.
An url like "/dataLoad.js" have to render this jsp, and you'll have your data available.